# Interpretation of surah 25 verse 53

Tags: quran, practical-islam, science

> “God is the one who caused two bodies of water to flow, one palpable **and sweet**, the other salty and **bitter**. 
>   He placed a barrier between them, a partition that they are forbidden to surmount”. ( Quran 25:53)

But what does the Quran mean by sweet and bitter? The river I believe the Quran is referring to is the Nile Delta but i don't think the river is sweat or bitter in anyway. Or does it mean, the water it self is sweet to drink, which doesn't make any sense as water shouldn't have any taste.

May Allah forgive me for my mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **And it is He, Who has let loose the two seas, one palatable and sweet, the other bitter and saltish, and there is a partition between
>   them, which is an insurmountable barrier**

This is more like the verse.

In this verse, God wasn't talking about the Nile Delta, that is just a normal river. God was talking about *any 2 bodies of water with different properties that mix*(e.i. ocean meets a river) The miracle that God mentioned is how one river that's water is clean, drinkable, and tastes very normal(doesn't taste bad) is intersecting with an ocean with it's salty, undrinkable, bad tasting water

[image: Gulf of Alaska]

The word "sweet" isn't used to describe the taste of water; it's just to show that water is drinkable, not harmful, and isn't mixed with salt although it is right beside salt water yet it never surmounts, and when God said "bitter" he was referring to the ocean because of the ocean's salt(translation from Arabic to English might not be that accurate)

Asking is always fine, ask whenever you have a misconception and you, in sha Allah, will find you'll answer